# Change default Sound Device Order

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, preferences

Basically, Ubuntu (-Mate 16.04) plays sound output on the first non-disabled sound-device in the preferences list:

[image]

Only trouble: **I'd like to change the order.** If there's a headset or that USB audio device connected, that should come first, internal card only as the last resort. (Currently I have to disable all higher-up soundcards)

I [played around with the `pacmd set-default-sink` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083#14083) (Indices are 0,6,7 on my machine) but no luck...

[Possibly related Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083). — [Possibly related Question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback).

Comment: Not sure if this would help with the issue, but I found an alternative that could work: [Fallback option](http://askubuntu.com/a/772685/602680)